# Interpolating a data point on a curve with a negative slope

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Hi I have two numpy arrays (in this case representing depth and percentage depth dose data) as follows:

```
depth = np.array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,
                   1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.2,
                   2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5])
pdd = np.array([  80.40649399,   80.35692155,   81.94323956,   83.78981286,
                  85.58681373,   87.47056637,   89.39149833,   91.33721651,
                  93.35729334,   95.25343909,   97.06283306,   98.53761309,
                  99.56624117,  100.        ,   99.62820672,   98.47564754,
                  96.33163961,   93.12182427,   89.0940637 ,   83.82699219,
                  77.75436857,   63.15528566,   46.62287768,   29.9665386 ,
                  16.11104226,    6.92774817,    0.69401413,    0.58247614,
                   0.55768992,    0.53290371,    0.5205106 ])
```

which when plotted give the following curve:

[image: Percentage Depth Dose]

I need to find the depth at which the pdd falls to a given value (initially 50%). I have tried slicing the arrays at the point where the pdd reaches 100% as I'm only interested in the points after this.

Unfortunately `np.interp` only appears to work where both x and y values are incresing.

Could anyone suggest where I should go next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to interpolate the function `depth = f(pdd)` at `pdd = 50.0`. For the purposes of the interpolation, it might help for you to think of `pdd` as corresponding to your "x" values, and `depth` as corresponding to your "y" values.

You can use [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to sort your "x" and "y" by ascending order of "x" (i.e. ascending `pdd`), then use `np.interp` as usual:

```
# `idx` is an an array of integer indices that sorts `pdd` in ascending order
idx = np.argsort(pdd)

depth_itp = np.interp([50.0], pdd[idx], depth[idx])

plt.plot(depth, pdd)
plt.plot(depth_itp, 50, 'xr', ms=20, mew=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. It works well.  

Combining this with slicing for values greater than pdd=100% means that it will also work for other values greater than 80%

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming solution, but it's how you can find the depth. I'm taking the liberty of renaming your variables, so `x(i) = depth(i)` and `y(i) = pdd(i)`.

In a given interval `[x(i),x(i+1)]`, your linear interpolant is

```
p_1(X) = y(i) + (X - x(i))*(y(i+1) - y(i))/(x(i+1) - x(i))
```

You want to find `X` such that `p_1(X) = 50`. First find `i` such that `x(i)>50` and `x(i+1)`, then the above equation can be rearranged to give

```
X = x(i) + (50 - y(i))*((x(i+1) - x(i))/(y(i+1) - y(i)))
```

For your data (with MATLAB; sorry, no python code) I make it approximately `2.359`. This can then be verified with `np.interp(X, depth, pdd)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to carry out interpolation. For your case, you are basically looking for the depth at 50% which is not available in your data. The simplest interpolation is the linear case. I'm using [numerical recipes](http://numerical.recipes/) library in C++ for acquiring the interpolated value via several techniques, therefore,

**Linear Interpolation:** see page 117

interpolated value depth(50%): **2.35915**

**Polynomial Interpolation:** see page 117

interpolated value depth(50%):  **2.36017**

**Cubic Spline Interpolation:** see page 120

interpolated value depth(50%):  **2.19401**

**Rational Function Interpolation:** see page 124

interpolated value depth(50%):  **2.35986**